# Write output to console and then read only errors if there are any using Python

Tags: python

I have to execute a command which does a db import. I am performing this action using `subprocess.Popen`.

I have to write the output to console if there are no errors in the process.

If there are any errors in the process I have to read them and display a customiszed message based on the error.

Comment: Read up on try/except, that should give you a good idea on how to approach this

Comment: So what have you tried so far? We will gladly help you but we won't do it for you.

Comment: I have tried following -- **p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, sterr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=False) and then output = p.stderr.readlines()** . but this is not displaying on console.

Comment: Popen do not raise runtime errors

Comment: So what would be the right way to display the output and capture only errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should run it with `check_call`

```
from subprocess import call_check, PIPE, CalledProcessError
>>> try:
...     check_call(['ls','-la', '/'], stdout=PIPE)
... except CalledProcessError as err:
...     raise YourException("Ouch! '%s'" % err)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is "When we specify *stdout=PIPE*, its not displaying o/p on the console immediately". So in this case user has to wait to see the o/p till the process ends execution. I want to have an approach where it can write the output to console and at the same time i can read the output for some error process.

Comment: I've read about buffering concepts to read the executing process data, but i did not understand it properly. Can some body explain it elaborately.

Comment: what is the better way to capture large data from subprocess. I was trying *subprocess.popen* by specifying buffered size as 64. But it is quite slow in reading the data from subprocess. I also read about communicate method but in doc it is mentioned as "do not use this method if the data size is large ".